# Flurry issue: Xcode 7 and Swift Language

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, flurry

I've implemented flurry 6.7.0 to my Xcode 7 project ( swift language ) as described in the page ::

https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/gettingstarted/swift/?soc_src=mail&soc_trk=ma

But when the project is building, i get this error message :

`ld: library not found for -lFlurry_6.7.0
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)`

How do i resolve the problem ? any idea please?

EDIT::

HOLY SHIT!! Just added .a file to copy bundle resources...
I thought that I have checked that before and still the problem is there........

EDIT 2::

now I have removed it without any problem

I don't know what was the problem :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you tu use CocoaPods to avoid all of these problems, flurry has a Pod, [here it is](https://cocoapods.org/?q=flurry), if your are not familiar with CocoaPods, [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64546/introduction-to-cocoapods-2) is a very straight forward tutorial

I Made It work

- Xcode 7 Beta 5
- CocoaPods v0.38.2

Here's my PodFile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'FlurryTest' do
    pod 'FlurrySDK', '~>6.6'
end
```

And then had to add manually a bridging header `Flurry-Bridging-Header.h` just with this content:

```
#import "Flurry.h"
```

Now add to your target Build Settings this under **Swift Compiler - Code Generation** in the value of **Objective-C Brinding Header**:

[image]

Then you just use it under your classes

[image]

And it compiles of course :D

Comment: And what if I don't want to use that? any recommendation to find out what the problem is?

Comment: I did so as you said, the problem is still there even with importing sdk using cocoa pod! TNX anyway

Comment: sent an email to flurry support, hope they help... :)

Comment: mmmm, maybe the problem is with xcode 7, have you tried with xcode 6? If they help you remember to share the solution :B

Comment: I tried to add GoogleAnalytics but something similar happened!!
`library not found for -lGGLAnalytics`

I'll try to use Xcode 6... thank you :)

Comment: wow.. millions of lines should be edited to be supported by swift 1.2..... what should I do now??? :/

Comment: perhaps in newer beta versions of Xcode 7 the problem is solved??
So i'll update that and see what happens.

Comment: So I think it's because of my old build of Xcode 7 for sure, I'll update it to beta 5 and check, thank you very much ;)
+I'll check my podFile again, too

Comment: Edited my question, THANK YOU BRO

Comment: The Cocoapod you refer to is not official and is also out of date. You should be using iOS SDK v6.7. I am working on getting an official pod created. Please upvote the feature request here: https://yahoo.uservoice.com/forums/309376

Comment: "use a cocoa pod" is not a valid response IMHO